# PhoneGap - application that has it's own user base from Facebook

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm planning to develop my first mobile app using PhoneGap. I'd like users to register using their FB account -- and I want to keep track of that information in a centralized database. Afterwards, I want that user to be able to access his/her FB friend's list and invite them to use the app. The app will have an aspect to it wherein the user and his/her friends all share the same data (e.g. say a game of scrabble where everyone is playing on the same board).

In PHP, I would have no problem using one of the OAuth libraries to do all that Facebook stuff, etc.

In PhoneGap, I'm not sure what I'll need to do (e.g. how do I register a user using FB? how do I access their contact list?). What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can register a user using FB and access their contact list using facebook connect plugin.

You can use this plugin  [PhoneGap Build plugin for Facebook Connect](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect).   for  further information about this plugin please refer http://phonegap.com/blog/build/adobe-phonegap-build-plugin-for-facebook-connect/
which will help you.